# algorithm to find the largest area

Tags: java, algorithm, graph

```
................................
.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.....XXXXXXXXXX.
.X.....X.......X.....X........X.
.X.....X.......XXXXXXX........X.
.XXXXXXXXXXXX.................X.
.X....X.....X.................X.
.X....X.....XXXX..............X.
.XXXXXX........X..............X.
......X........X..............X.
......X........X..............X.
......X........X..............X.
......XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
................................
```

Looking for an algorithm to find the largest area. Here, "area" is defined as a number of dots (.) bounded by Xs.

```
   private static void readFile(File inputFile) throws IOException {

    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(inputFile);

    Point previousPoint = null;

    int rowCount = 0;
    while(fileScanner.hasNext()){
        String line = fileScanner.next();

        String[] points = line.split(" ");

        for(int columnCount=0;columnCount<points.length;columnCount++){

            if(points[columnCount].equalsIgnoreCase("x")){
                Point currentPoint = new Point();
                currentPoint.setxValue(columnCount);
                currentPoint.setyValue(rowCount);
            }
        }

        rowCount++;
    }
  }
```

This is my first and struggling to move further.

Comment: where is your attempt

Comment: Must appreciate the time you spent, properly designing this in the question window.

Comment: is it a boolean[][] array, or what?

Comment: your attempt, where is it?

Comment: First count the dots in each area. Then return the area with the highest number.

Comment: I have no clue on this. Looking for some help to attempt this.

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm for this.

Comment: @user1578872 I'm gonna be nice. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill start here. Try to come up with something, something to tell us you've at least thought about the problem, and then ask again

Comment: thanks for the link, i will try it out and come back with my attempt ...

Comment: Tip:  Add @Cruncher (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* them of a new comment.  As an aside, I am dismayed at the number of down-votes this question got.  People seem quick to judge, allowing no time to edit a post (as you did).  I voted to re-open it, but don't hold much hope of that happening.  If you cannot solve it from the advice offered, notify me and I'll have a think about the best way to proceed..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I gave reopen vote 4.  Hopefully we see one more

Comment: @user1578872 The general idea you want is to essentially pick the first ".", Then follow this flood fill algorithm changing the dots to something else, maybe a "," counting how many you changed. After this terminates, you have one number. Next, find the next "." (it will be in a different square, because you changed all the other ones to ","). Rinse and repeat until there's no .'s left, and save what the biggest box was.

Comment: @Nirk  Wow!  Got to say, I've never seen re-open votes to be that effective.  Not until this question at least!  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson -6 to +5. This is bananas.

Comment: @Cruncher  (chuckle) Yes.  I guess we just have to 'agree to disagree' with the various detractors.  ;)  Nice answer, BTW.

Comment: @AndrewThompson http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166869/what-is-this-generated-code-supposed-intended-to-do swung from -4 to +14, was closed and then reopened when I realized what was happening (see my +13 comment)

Comment: @Nirk I won't up-vote the comment, just your answer.  ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This algorithm should work. You just need to implement it in Java.

> 1. Load the file into a char[][]. (1 char[] per line)
> 2. Loop through the char[][] (2 dimensionally)
>
>    3. upon finding a '.', perform [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), changing all '.' to ',', also incrementing a counter on every change.
>    4. At the end of flood fill, compare this counter with a globally set maximum. If it's higher, then set it as the new highest. (If the edges are not a proper boundary, then do not set this counter if you reached an edge during flood fill by setting a flag during 3)
> 3. Return the highest you set.

If you have any specific problems with the Java implementation, then let me know

Geobits:

> Note: If you want to exclude the area "outside" any boxes, flood as
>   usual, but discard any area that hits the edge during the fill(skip
>   step 2.2 for that flood).

When doing the flood fill, you have 2 types of boundaries. A wall ('X'), and the edge of the array(which you need to explicitly check for to avoid OutOfBounds exceptions). If you hit an out of bounds, keep doing the fill, but set a flag so you know later to not consider the number you counted for the biggest box.

Comment: Note: If you want to exclude the area "outside" any boxes, flood as usual, but discard any area that hits the edge during the fill(skip step 2.2 for that flood).

Comment: I know its been so long but just wondering how do we approach  this problem if the dots and X's are in a cube.

Comment: @Sree should be exactly the same. But you'll have to flood fill in 3 dimensions instead of 2. Should be a trivial modification.

Answer (score 0):

I was given this as assignment in an interview process and this is the compile and running code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class FindArea {
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String fileName="C:\\map.txt";
    FindArea area = new FindArea();
    try{
        FileReader inputFile = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputFile);

        char[][] twoArray= new char[100][100];
        String line;
        int i=0;

        while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
            twoArray[i] = line.toCharArray();
            System.out.println(line);
            i++;
        }
        bufferReader.close();

        System.out.println("file read");
        System.out.println("Max area: " + area.getMaxArea(twoArray));

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * Get the maximum area from the given map
 * 
 * @param charArray
 * @return
 */
private int getMaxArea(char[][] charArray) {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> numberOfBoxes = convertToBoxes(charArray);

    numberOfBoxes = mergeOverlapAreas(numberOfBoxes);

    int largeSize = 0; 
    for (Integer key : numberOfBoxes.keySet()) {
        ArrayList<String> list = numberOfBoxes.get(key);
        System.out.println("Key : " + key + " Size : " + list.size());
        if (largeSize < list.size()) {
            largeSize = list.size();
        }
    }
    return largeSize;
}

/**
 * Convert the 2d Array to HashMap
 * Key being the count of boxes and 
 * Value being the list of indexes associations
 * 
 * @param charArray
 * @return
 */
private HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> convertToBoxes(char[][] charArray) {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> numberOfBoxes = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
    int boxes = 0;

    for(int i=1; i<charArray.length; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j<charArray[i].length; j++) {

            if (charArray[i][j] == '.') {

                boolean isExists = false;

                for(Integer key : numberOfBoxes.keySet()) {

                    ArrayList<String> arrList = numberOfBoxes.get(key);

                    if(arrList != null) {

                        if(arrList.contains((i-1) + "-" + j) ||
                           arrList.contains(i + "-" + (j-1))) {

                            isExists = true;
                            arrList.add(i + "-" + j);
                            numberOfBoxes.put(key, arrList);
                        }
                    } 
                }

                if (!isExists) {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                    list.add(i + "-" + j);
                    numberOfBoxes.put(boxes, list);
                    boxes++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return numberOfBoxes;
}

/**
 * Check for the points exists in more than one area
 * @param numberOfBoxes
 * @return
 */
private  HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> mergeOverlapAreas( HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> numberOfBoxes) {

    for(Integer key : numberOfBoxes.keySet()) {
        ArrayList<String> list1 = numberOfBoxes.get(key);

        for (Integer key2 : numberOfBoxes.keySet()) {

            if (key < key2) {

                ArrayList<String> list2 = numberOfBoxes.get(key2);
                Iterator<String> listIter = list2.iterator();

                while(listIter.hasNext()) {

                    if (list1.contains(listIter.next())) {
                        list1.addAll(list2);
                        Set<String> noDuplicates = new HashSet<String>(list1);
                        numberOfBoxes.put(key, new ArrayList<String>(noDuplicates));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return numberOfBoxes;
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an algorithm that's an alternative to flood fill. This method sweeps through the 2d array and whenever you encounter a node(pixel) that's outside to the left (right, top, bottom), it flags the current node as outside, ie if your neighbour is 'outside', you're marked 'outside' too.

The algorithm continues like this until there're no more updates. That means that all the nodes that are reachable from the 'outside' have been flagged. BTW, this is a very similar problem to level sets functions and updating them (where flood fill is also used). The nice this about this method is that it is ideal for parallelization.

```
1. Load 2D Symbol Array from File 
2. hasupdates = false
3. Create 'isinside' bool array -> {
       if(symbolarray[row][col] == '.' and row or col is at boundary)
           isinside[row][col] = false
       else
           isinside[row][col] = true
   }

4. do{
    Do a sweep from left to right (for all rows) -> //This loop can be run parallely on all rows. 
        If (!isinside[row][col-1] and symbolarray[row][col] == '.'){
            isinside[row][col] = false //mark current value as 'outside'
            hasupdates = true
        }
    Do similar sweeps from right to left, top to bottom(all columns) and bottom to top.

}while(hasupdates)

5. Go through 'isinside' array and count the number of falses.
```

If you have huge files where you have to do this area calculation, you can have the sweeps along the rows and columns run parallely, because each row update (column update) is independent of the other updates.

Comment: Will this not just find everything that is not outside ALL(union of) boxes? We need to compare several different boundaries

Comment: As written, I think it just marks *everything* as outside. If you sweep left to right and the first one is outside, then every "left neighbor" on that sweep will be.

Comment: @Geobits. I fixed the logic. Thanks for pointing. When flagging as 'outside', one need to check if the neighbour is outside AND if one's own value is '.' .

Comment: That does make more sense, but Cruncher's comment is more crucial, I think.

Comment: @Geobits Ok. I totally missed the 'largest' part. Will try to see if area of individual regions can be calculated using the 'sweep' methods.